# Installing PHP on a server where HTTPD was installed by source

Tags: php, apache, redhat, yum

There is one server where Apache HTTPD was installed by source, so, there is no Yum/RPM register of installed Apache HTTPD.

When trying to install PHP 5.x packages using yum, it gives errors saying the dependent package "httpd" was not found.

What's the correct approach to install PHP and the remaining PHP RPM children packages (as example php-pecl-jsonc RPM), since yum is not allowing it to be installed?

Comment: At that point I install PHP from sources as well (php.net).  Look at the install documentation for the version you want.

Comment: Nic3500 I found this solution also, but I'd like to install the .rpm as I have a group of other dependant php rpms and I'd have to find the source from all of these and it would make my installation manuals bigger and more complex.

Comment: Do you have the option of installing httpd via yum?

Comment: Unfortunatelly no Nic350, the client has an infrastructure requirement to use the Apache from his internal team. They have done a workaround installing the Apache RPM at the server to be able to push all dependant RPMs, but now all environment variables and service pid are pointing to the RPM Apache (not their source build Apache). I am trying to guide them to fix these two points and looks like it will work! Otherwise, I will have to build a whole process based on the sources for all RPMs :) I will update the answer when I get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved installing the PHP RPM files ignoring the dependencies from HTTPD and then moving the mod_php files (mod_php.so) from the original source directory into the respective modules directory from the HTTPD installed by source.